# AppInventor: QR code for .apk does not allow to download apk file

Tags: apk, qr-code, app-inventor

I've built a simple "HelloWorld" Android app with MIT AppInventor and I would like to install it in my Smartphone. The App Inventor IDE offers me two choices from the 'Build' menu:

- Provide QR code for .apk
- Save .apk to my computer
  The second option works: I transfer the .apk file to my smartphone and when I open the .apk file, the app gets installed.

But if I scan the generated QR code, it doesn't lead to the .apk file itself. Check for example the QR code in the image

[image: QR code for HelloWorld .apk]

If you scan it with your phone, it takes you to the following url: [ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/b/aj94](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/b/aj94), which is not a download link for the .apk file.

I remember to have installed app-inventor apps with QR codes with the old IDE, but I can't make it work now.

Comment: ok, it seems the problem is my QR scanner not downloading the file. The url actually takes to the apk file

Comment: the QR code is also only valid for 2 hours, see also [Sharing Your App](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/share.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the download folder in your phone and change the name of the file from `namexxx` to `namexxx.apk`, with the permission of installing from others and the AI2 MIT companion. It should work.